# Tagging page tracker event using the Async google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, asynchronous

In the old GA.js I was doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  pageTracker._trackPageview("/Page/About_Us/");
</script>
```

What is the equivalent using the asynchronous analytics code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer --
first turn off the gaq.push that does a _trackPageview in the default async script
then use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/whatever/you/need']);
//]]>
</script>
```